# When would javax.servlet.Filter.doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) be called with anything other than HttpServletRequest/Response?

Tags: java, servlets

I've been writing servlets and filters for years and it is something that has always irked me a little - the checking and casting of `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` parameters to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`, particularly with filters as there is no standard `HttpFilter` base class to do this for you - unlike servlets.

The question is - when would you ever see anything other that `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` being passed to your servlet/filter and what should you do if you do?

Comment: The JSF utility library OmniFaces has a [`HttpFilter`](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/filters/HttpFilter.xhtml).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In some yet-to-be-realized world where there are other servlet types besides HttpServlets.

Comment: Word. What some call the "we might need it someday" architecture approach. Or what they call "waste" at Toyota.

Comment: Thanks for that - I have created my own HttpFilter class based on what HttpServlet does and I'll only worry about changing it when somebody invents a new protocol for the web.

Comment: @pauli It doesn't have to take a new protocol. You can imagine an FTPServlet for example.

Comment: @EJP of course you're right. As long as I am running in Tomcat or Jetty then it will only ever be http. If I had a servlet container that supported FTP then I could get FTPServletRequest/Response.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood going through API, servlet specifications is that the servlet framework has been created for HTTP/web use specifically.

The protocols mentioned under reference section of the servlet specification are all related to HTTP only viz. 

*RFC 1945 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.0) 

RFC 2616 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1) 

RFC 2617 HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Authentication

RFC 2324 Hypertext Coffee Pot Control Protocol (HTCPCP/1.0) -- this is basd on HTTP*


 
All these are HTTP protocols.

Also the spec mandates this:

> All servlet containers must support HTTP as a protocol for requests and responses, but may
>   also support other request / response based protocols such as HTTPS (HTTP over SSL).

And the reason for having GenericServlet -> HttpServlet is to have the Generalization -> towards Specialization kind of hierarchy in the API structure in the API.