# Servlet filters: is there `doFilter(HttpServletRequest)`

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

The servlet API defines a `GenericServlet` which accepts `ServletRequest` objects, and subclasses it to `HttpServlet` which accepts `HttpServletRequest`. However, `Filter.doFilter` seems to accept only `ServletRequest`. Is there filter class specific to HTTP requests? If not

- Why? Since HTTP is the only method common to all web compoments, wouldn't it make sense to have an HTTP-specific filter, just like servlets? What is the rationale?
- How should I pass the `ServletRequest` to the `HttpServletRequestWrapper`? Do I have to downcast it manually, or is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: Relevant: [When would javax.servlet.Filter.doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) be called with anything other than HttpServletRequest/Response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350053/when-would-javax-servlet-filter-dofilterservletrequest-req-servletresponse-res)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not the only one who wished this for ages. There's actually no reasonable rationale for this. The upcoming Servlet 4.0 (part of Java EE 8) will therefore as per [spec issue 141](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-141) finally come with a `javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter`. It's currently already [implemented](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpFilter.html) in [Tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi). The method signature is:

```
protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        FilterChain chain)
```

Until then, your best bet is baking a `HttpFilter` yourself, or if you happen to use a JSF+CDI based web application, grab [OmniFaces `HttpFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/HttpFilter) (which is [open source](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/filter/HttpFilter.java), so you could use it as inspiration for baking on your own), which happens to have the following signature:

```
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     HttpSession session,
                     FilterChain chain)
```

Whereby the `session` is `null` if it isn't created yet.

As to your secondary question,

> *How should I pass the `ServletRequest` to the `HttpServletRequestWrapper`? Do I have to downcast it manually, or is there a more appropriate way?*

Just look at [existing code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aa%20HttpServletRequestWrapper%20HttpServletRequest) here for several real world exapmles.